# $ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac {e^{x/2}}{2^x} $

Tags: calculus

How do i know what is the limit :

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac {e^{x/2}}{2^x} $$

Because with l'hopital it is imposible to say, as the nth derivatives of  both $ {e^{x/2}} $and  $  {2^x}$ are always infinity...
I could use a hint that helps me think this through

Comment: Hint: $2^x=e^{x\ln 2}$.

Comment: $2^x = 4^{\frac {x}{2}} \implies \frac {e^{\frac x2}}{2^x} = \left(\frac e4\right)^{\frac x2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Hint:

$$\large\frac{e^{x/2}}{2^x}=\frac{e^{x/2}}{e^{x\ln(2)}}=e^{x\left[\frac12-\ln(2)\right]}\to\ ...$$

Answer (score 1):

For a slightly different perspective from the other answer, your limit is the same as
$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \left( \frac{\sqrt e}{2} \right)^x,$$
which will go to $\infty$ if $\sqrt e > 2$ or $0$ if $\sqrt e < 2$.

[Note that this is essentially the same as considering the sign of $\frac{1}{2} - \ln 2$ as in the other answer.]

Comment: I think this is the simplest answer.